# URL's with ?attachment redirect instead of 404 http://www.customlogoshop.com/?attachment_id=719

Tags: http-status-code-301

I want all http://www.customlogoshop.com/?attachment_id=719 these type of URL's to go to a 404 page but its just 301 redirect to my homepage.

It's only my URL's with '?attachment' that does this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wondering the same, I got a url with ?attachment_id=000 to ?attachment_id=999 and i want all the url to go to a custom url.

I try something like this:

```html
redirect 301 /?attachment_id=837 http://google.com
RewriteRule ?attachment_id(.*) / [R=301, L]
```